# Admob 3.1.0 showing errors in Unity 5.4.1f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I have Unity 5.4.1f1
I have the admob Unity sdk version 3.1.0

I setup an admob account, and then followed [these steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/unity/start)

When I do a build for Android I get the following errors

[image]

When I play I get the following messages

[image]

Heres the full version of one of those errors

```
    WARNING: No compatible versions of com.android.support:support-v4 required by (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0+, com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1), will try using the latest version 24.0.0
    UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
    Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:Log(String, Boolean)
    Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:ResolveDependencies(Boolean)
    GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolutionNoAndroidPackageChecks(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation)
    GooglePlayServices.<DoResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
    GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolution(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation, Action)
    GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action)
    GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:AutoResolve()
    UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

Note that I already have Chartboost working.

I have so far been unable to display an admob ad in the editor or in a build with the following code.

```
    private void RequestAdmobInterstitial()
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "my ad unit id";
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
        #else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
        InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the interstitial with the request.
        interstitial.LoadAd(request);
    }
```

In a build nothing happens, in the editor I get these messages

[image]

Are these errors why it is it working?
If so how do I fix them?

Answer (score 1):

This error:

```
WARNING: No compatible versions of com.android.support:support-v4
```

The script complaining about it is the google play jar resolver. It grabs all the necessary android libraries from your Android SDK location, and it can't find the libraries it wants.

This most likely means you are missing the android support libraries in your Android SDK folder.

To fix this, open up the Android SDK manager (most likely via Android Studio) and make sure you have the support libraries up to date.

While you're at it, update google play services too, cant hurt and might save you errors down the road.

[image: Android Support Libraries]

Comment: Yeah I thought of that. In my android sdk manager I have the 'Android support repository' installed but the 'Android support library' shown in your image does not show up at all in my extras,,, EDIT just checked and it shows up if I list obsolete packages. Ill try installing it

Comment: Also btw I dont think I'll even bother with using admobs after all this. Their Unity support is terrible. I'm shocked how bad it is considering Unity is probably the biggest mobile game engine and admob is probably the biggest mobile ad provider. I'm looking at Fyber now

Comment: In my opinion, you should just use one network and be really vigilant with campaign optimization. In theory, yes a mediation campaign will get you the best ecpm, but in practice, a well optimized single network beats the hell out of 4 unoptimised ones. It's much easier to keep track of one network and squeeze the most you can out of it. I have worked at companies where it's one person's whole job just to optimize publishing campaigns, and I doubt you have the time for that.

Comment: Thanks! thats very interesting, I initially got Chartboost working and then realized that they only provide so many ads per user in a certain timeslot, so I thought I'd ad a few more ad providers to ensure I always have an ad to display in between levels, Then it turns out integrating admobs is tricky and someone recommended I use an ad mediator service like fyber which I am looking at atm

Comment: So I could just focus on Chartboost and perhaps one other service with a  high fill rate to fill in the gaps?

Comment: In theory yes that is not a bad idea. Again, just my opinion, but you should not be worried about fill rate. If you are hitting your fill rate then you are showing too many ADs. And if the user is in a place where chartboost does not have any ADs, then the return on those ADs that do get shown will be tiny, so up to you to decide if it is worth the extra work.