# GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.35 and Unity 5.4.2f1: WARNING: No compatible versions of com.android.support:support-annotations

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, google-play-services, android-sdk-manager

So I've tried implementing Google Play Services in my Unity project. The problem is, that these two warnings always appear
[Warnings in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQAXz.png)

```
WARNING: No compatible versions of com.android.support:support-v4 required by (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1), will try using the latest version 24.0.0
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:Log(String, Boolean)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:ResolveDependencies(Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolutionNoAndroidPackageChecks(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolution(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation, Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:AutoResolve()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

WARNING: No compatible versions of com.android.support:support-annotations required by (com.android.support:support-v4:23.1+, com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0), will try using the latest version 24.0.0
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:Log(String, Boolean)
Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport:ResolveDependencies(Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolutionNoAndroidPackageChecks(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation)
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0()
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:DoResolution(PlayServicesSupport, String, OverwriteConfirmation, Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Resolve(Action)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:AutoResolve()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

I have found this question: [Admob 3.1.0 showing errors in Unity 5.4.1f1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003657/admob-3-1-0-showing-errors-in-unity-5-4-1f1?newreg=2e6bd2d39cc6410d955d3d77665cf543)
but because I have already updated everything in the SDK Manager [SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/346Vp.png) I don't know what else to check?

Comment: somewhere in your project, there is a script stating that the resolver should resolve the dependancy com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.6.1.

Find that and try changing 9.6.1 to 9.6.0

If that solves the first error, then try bringing the other dependancys down a bit too.

Comment: I got same problem. I think this error came with the last version, google updated play services plugin 3 days ago. I hope they will fix it soon.